# Determinant is alternating over a commutative ring with $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In Section 11.4 of Dummit and Foote, they introduce a determinant function $\det$ on the ring of $n\times n$ matrices over a commutative ring $R$ with $1$ as

1. Any $n$-multilinear alternating form, where the $n$-tuples are the $n$ columns of the matrices in $M_{n\times n}(R)$, and
2. $\det(I) = 1$ where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

They then define a function
$$
\det(\alpha_{ij}) = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\alpha_{\sigma(1)1}\dotsb\alpha_{\sigma(n)n}
$$
and show that the determinant is unique, but they leave it as an exercise to show that the function $\det$ defined above is actually a determinant function.

Note that Dummit and Foote take alternating to mean that if two consecutive columns of the matrix $(\alpha_{ij})$ are equal, then the alternating form returns $0$ when applied to $(\alpha_{ij})$.

I am having trouble showing that $\det$ so-defined is alternating. I have managed to show that if a matrix $(\alpha_{ij})$ has two consecutive columns equal, say the $j$th and $j+1$st, then $\det(\alpha_{ij})=-\det(\alpha_{ij})$. I am not sure if this is sufficient to show that $\det(\alpha_{ij}) = 0$ since we are in a commutative ring with $1$, which may have zero divisors.

Is there an easy fix? I can supply my proof if need be. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. In the field with two elements (say), the equation $\det(A) = -\det(A)$ yields no new information--it might be best to argue the determinant is alternating directly.

Here's the idea for the 3x3 case, assuming that the first two columns of the matrix are equal. Let $G = S_3$ and let $H$ be the (two element) subgroup generated by the transposition $\tau := (1, 2)$. Then partition $G$ into *cosets* $G/H$. In this specific example, $G/H = \{\{(1), \tau\}, \{(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)\tau\}, \{(2,3), (2,3)\tau\}\}$. Note that each coset has two permutations in it, some permutation, and then a transposition multiplied by that permutation.

Then recalling that the first two columns of the matrix are equal, you obtain that the determinant is \begin{align*}
\sum_{\sigma \in S_3} \mathrm{sign}(\sigma)a_{\sigma(1)1}a_{\sigma(2)2}a_{\sigma(3)3} &= \sum_{S \in G/H}\sum_{\sigma \in S}\mathrm{sign}(\sigma)a_{\sigma(1)1}a_{\sigma(2)2}a_{\sigma(3)3} \\
&= \sum_{S \in G/H, choose (\sigma) \in S} (\pm a_{\sigma(1)1}a_{\sigma(2)2}a_{\sigma(3)3} \mp a_{\sigma \tau(1)1}a_{\sigma \tau(2)2}a_{\sigma \tau(3)3}) \\
&= \sum_{S \in G/H, choose (\sigma) \in S} (\pm a_{\sigma(1)1}a_{\sigma(2)2}a_{\sigma(3)3} \mp a_{\sigma (2)1}a_{\sigma (1)2}a_{\sigma (3)3}) \\
&\stackrel{*}= \sum_{S \in G/H, choose (\sigma) \in S} (\pm a_{\sigma(1)2}a_{\sigma(2)1}a_{\sigma(3)3} \mp a_{\sigma (2)1}a_{\sigma (1)2}a_{\sigma (3)3}) \\
&= \sum_{S \in G/H, choose (\sigma) \in S} 0 \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

where $\stackrel{*}=$ uses the fact that the first two columns agree. (Note: the sum looks scary, but the *idea* is not nearly as scary.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not sure what you mean by suggesting to show that the determinant is alternating directly. In my mind, that is what I tried to show, but I came up with my problem.

Comment: I mean you should show that after you switch two rows, each entry in that big sum is multiplied by -1 when computing the determinant of the new matrix.

Comment: Okay, but note that my definition of alternating is that when two adjacent columns (or rows) are equal, then the determinant function should evaluate to $0$. What you are suggesting doesn't seem to get me further in the right direction.

Comment: You're absolutely right, my apologies! I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah, beautiful; I was able to turn this into a proof of the general case with no problem. I didn't think of partitioning $G$ into its cosets; does this idea come up in any other proofs you know of? Thanks very much!

Comment: I can't think of many (but to be honest, I thought of that proof just now--I've always proven the determinant was symmetric using the "negation/column switching" definition of alternating), but one thing that comes to mind is that given any transitive group action $G$ on a set, you can use this kind of idea to argue that if $H$ is the stabilizer of your favorite element in the set, the group action is "$G$ isomorphic" to the $G$ action on $G/H$ (note: $G/H$ may not necessarily be a group, but the statement holds in full generality.) This is essentially a beefed up Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem.

Comment: Very interesting. Where does $H$ come in to play in this particular example?

Comment: If $H = stab(x)$ and $y$ is in the set, by transitivity $y = gx$ for some $g \in G$. Then the stabilizer of $y$ is $Hg^{-1}$ (exercise!)

Answer (score 4):

For a fully elaborated proof, I shall be lazy and just refer to Exercise 6.7 **(e)** in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, version of 10 January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10). Or the proof of property (iii) in §5.3.4 of [Hartmut Laue, *Determinants*](http://www.uni-kiel.de/math/algebra/laue/homepagetexte/det.pdf). The main idea is to split the sum $\sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_n} \ldots$ into a sum over all even permutations and a sum over all odd permutations, and show that the addends in the two sums mutually cancel, as Tom Gannon suggests.

**However,** there is also a way to derive the result from your $\det \left(\alpha_{i,j}\right) = - \det \left(\alpha_{i,j}\right)$ observation. Namely, fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\right\}$. Let a *$k$-col-equal matrix* be a matrix whose $k$-th column equals its $k+1$-st column. Your claim is that a $k$-col-equal matrix must have determinant $0$. Now, observe that you can derive $u = 0$ from $u = -u$ when $u$ is a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$ (for example). Thus, you can prove your claim whenever the entries of the $k$-col-equal matrix are polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ (because you have shown that each $k$-col-equal matrix $\left(\alpha_{i,j}\right)$ satisfies $\det \left(\alpha_{i,j}\right) = - \det \left(\alpha_{i,j}\right)$). In particular, your claim holds when the col-equal matrix is the "universal $k$-col-equal matrix", which is the matrix whose entries are indeterminates (in a polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$) that are distinct except for the two columns that are supposed to be equal. (For example, the universal $2$-col-equal matrix for $n = 4$ is $\left(\begin{array}{cccc} x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} & x_{1,2} & x_{1,4} \\ x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} & x_{2,2} & x_{2,4} \\ x_{3,1} & x_{3,2} & x_{3,2} & x_{3,4} \\ x_{4,1} & x_{4,2} & x_{4,2} & x_{4,4} \end{array}\right)$, where the $x_{i,j}$ are distinct indeterminates in a polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$.) But you can view an arbitrary $k$-col-equal matrix as a result of substituting concrete values for these indeterminates in the "universal $k$-col-equal matrix". Therefore, since your claim holds for the latter matrix, it must also hold for the former.

Comment: This is a very interesting take on it. One that I had not considered, but that is very nice. It's good to know that the original result can still get us to the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we take a matrix $(\alpha_{i,j})$, and switch the $p$th and $q$th rows to form another matrix $(\beta_{i,j})$, which is to say,
$$\beta_{i,j} = \left\lbrace \begin{array}{ccc} \alpha_{i, p} &\mathrm{if} & j = q \\ \alpha_{i, q} &\mathrm{if} & j = p \\ \alpha_{i, j} & & \mathrm{otherwise}\end{array} \right.$$
Another way to put it is, if we let $\tau = (p ~ q) \in S_n$, then,
$$\beta_{i,j} = \alpha_{i, \tau(j)}$$
So we have,
$$\det(\beta_{i,j}) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i \in \lbrace 1, \ldots, n \rbrace} \alpha_{\sigma(i),\tau(i)}.$$
If we reindex the above product in terms of $j = \tau(i) \iff i = \tau(j)$, then $j$ ranges over $\lbrace 1, \ldots, n \rbrace$ as well (note the importance of commutativity in this step), and we have,
$$\det(\beta_{i,j}) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{j \in \lbrace 1, \ldots, n \rbrace} \alpha_{\sigma \circ \tau(j),j}.$$
We can now reindex the sum with $\psi = \sigma \circ \tau \iff \sigma = \psi \circ \tau$, giving us
$$\det(\beta_{i,j}) = \sum_{\psi \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\psi \circ \tau) \prod_{j \in \lbrace 1, \ldots, n \rbrace} \alpha_{\psi(j),j}.$$
But, since composing a permutation with a transposition changes its sign, we thus have,
$$\det(\beta_{i,j}) = -\sum_{\psi \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\psi) \prod_{j \in \lbrace 1, \ldots, n \rbrace} \alpha_{\psi(j),j} = \det(\alpha_{i,j}).$$

Comment: Do you mean to say switch the two columns? My indexing convention is that if I have $a_{ij}$, then $i$ denotes the row, and $j$ the column.

Comment: Also, you have apparently shown what I have, which is that switching two rows (or columns) amounts to changing the sign. I am trying to show that if two neighboring columns (or rows) are identical, then the determinant is zero.